# open a new webpage on click of tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code .. i want to open facebook when i click on second tab ie tab2

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();

return false;
    });

});
</script>
</head> 

<body> 

<div class="container"> 
    <ul class="tabs"> 
        <li><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#tab4">tab4</a></li> 
    </ul> 
        <div class="tab_container"> 
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content"> 


    <p>No Data Available</p>
    </div> 

    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content" > 

    </div> 

    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content"> 

        </div> 
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content"> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 


</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
<li><a href="http://facebook.com">tab2</a></li>
```

Though I will say making a tab a link is highly unintuitive and not good UI practice.

Comment: i using #tab2 to open new and tab so i cant specify www.facebook.com over there

Comment: if it's not working then jQuery is over-riding the default behavior of the link. In which case, you need to apply a new behavior. Give the second tab an ID of `facebook` and then you can try `$('#facebook').click(function(){ document.location.href='http://facebook.com'})`

Comment: Also, what do you mean you're using '#tab2' to open a tab? Are you opening a tab or are you linking to Facebook? You can't do both.

Comment: when i click on that tab it should open faceboook.com.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">tab2</a></li>
```

Comment: That's because you attached your other click event to the `li` and you're returning false.  Remove the `return false`.

Comment: i using #tab2 to open new and tab so i cant specify www.facebook.com over there

Comment: if i remove return false it will not comeback to tab1. although its not working

Comment: "it will not comeback to tab1"...why would it? You've already left the page and gone to Facebook, right?

Answer (score 1):

Then set `href='http://www.facebook.com'` to tag2 like this :

```
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">tab2</a></li>
```

Comment: i using #tab2 to open new and tab so i cant specify www.facebook.com over there

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the Facebook link from the click event so that you can use a normal link in its place.

Change the click event code to:

```
$("ul.tabs li:not(.external)").click(function() { 
    ...
```

and the tab that should open Facebook to

```
<li class="external"><a href="http://www.facebook.com">tab2</a></li>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eBHa5/

Comment: thanks a lot. its working now. but if i want it to open in same page

Comment: What do you mean 'same page'? Are you asking to load facebook *inside* your tabbed area? If so, that's an entirely different question (the answer would be to stick an iFrame in that tab that points to facebook...though that's not a great UI either)

Comment: i want to open facebook in inner html without loading the whole page